# How do I define the delete behaviour of a one to one parent child hierarchie using EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parent-child, entity-framework-core

**Given**

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Entity
{
    public Customer Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I only have *one level* hierarchie.

**Question**

How do I define the delete behaviour of a parent child hierarchie using EF Core 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delete behavior can be specified only with fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Parent)
    .WithMany() // or .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

But note that your model is recursive, which is treated as multiple cascade paths, so `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` and `DeleteBehavior.SetNull` are not applicable. You have to choose between `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` (by default w/o fluent configuration) and `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull`, but in both cases you'll need to handle the deletion by hand or with database trigger.

Comment: The documentation says SetNull is the default. If I have more references on my Customer object, what expression do I need to put in o WithOne(x => x.?)?

Comment: The default is `Cascade` for required and `ClientSetNull` for optional relationships - see Cascade Delete section of [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships). As of what would you put in `WithOne`, it depends of the presence of inverse navigation property (which you didn't show) and how it is named. The above is for your sample model (no inverse property). In case you add `public Customer Child { get; set; }` to `Customer`, then you would use `HasOne(e => e.Parent).WithOne(e => e.Child)`